# Shopware plugin works on 5.2 and 5.3 but doesnt work on 5.1.6

Tags: shopware

I have a plugin which works on shopware 5.2 and 5.3 but doesnt work on 5.1.6. Here is the start file which is called ebTaxApi.php and i believe something should be changed here, but I need help:

```
<?php

namespace ebTaxApi;

use Shopware\Components\Plugin;

class ebTaxApi extends Plugin
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Dispatcher_ControllerPath_Api_Tax' => 'onGetTaxApiController',
        'Enlight_Controller_Front_StartDispatch' => 'onEnlightControllerFrontStartDispatch'
    ];
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function onGetTaxApiController()
{
    return $this->getPath() . '/Controllers/Api/Tax.php';
}

/**
 *
 */
public function onEnlightControllerFrontStartDispatch()
{
          $this->container->get('loader')->registerNamespace('Shopware\Components', $this->getPath() . '/Components/');
}
}
```

THis plugin is verified and works on 5.2 and 5.3 but i have tried to make its way into 5.1.6 but no luck. Also tried to register the namespace using a function but didnt work, the class could not be found.
Any help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Plugin-Class you are showing here is based on the new Plugin-System, wich was introduced in [Shopware Version 5.2](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-system/). If you need your Plugin in older Shopware versions, you need to use the [legacy plugin system](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-quick-start/).